# How should I expand $\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$ to find the residue and order at the pole z = 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

$\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$ is the function I want to expand. I tried using the expansion for $e^z$ and got $$\frac{1}{z^2+z^3/2!+z^4/3!+...}$$
Can I put this fraction into the $b_n/(z-z_0)^n$ form, or did I take the wrong approach?

Comment: I think this is basically a duplicate of this one:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744250/laurent-series-and-taylor-expansion-of-1-ez-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can do with some few terms:

$$\frac1{z(e^z-1)}=\frac1z\cdot\frac1{z\left(1+\frac z2+\mathcal O(z^2)\right)}=\frac1{z^2}\left(1-\frac z2+\frac{z^2}4-\ldots\right)=\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{2z}+\ldots$$

So the pole is double and its residue is $\;-\dfrac12\;$ .

Comment: I don't understand how you went from the 2nd to the 3rd equality.

Comment: @user224740 Since we can assume $\;|z|\;$ is very small, and in fact $\;|z|<2\;$ , then $\;\frac1{1+z}=1-z+z^2-z^3+\ldots\;$  Observe we don't need to worry about elements with high exponents as you're only interested in the pole's order and in the function's residue at it.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$z=0$ is a simple zero both for $z$ and $e^z-1$, hence $z=0$ is a double pole for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$ and:
$$\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z=0) = \left.\frac{d}{dz}(z^2 f(z))\right|_{z=0}=\left.\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{e^z-1}\right|_{z=0}=B_1=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}} $$
by the definition of [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).